# VBA pull data from multiple closed files

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = "c:\Vouchers\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.csv??")

Do While fileName <> ""

Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)

For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
total = Workbooks("Voucher Report 26MAR V1.0.xlsm").Worksheets.Count
Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
after:=Workbooks("Voucher Report 26MAR V1.0.xlsm").Worksheets(total)
Next sheet

Workbooks(fileName).Close

fileName = Dir()

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

The above code gets all the data I need but creates a new sheet for each workbook, is there anyway to place the data from the first workbook in row 10 then add the data from the next workbook in the next available row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try. Note, you may have to adjust the value of your `Dest` worksheet, I've defined it the best I could based on your code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer
Dim Dest as Worksheet
Dim DestRow as long
Dim Source as Workbook

'adjust this as necessary - it should create a new sheet at the end of 
'"Voucher Report...", and call it "My New Sheet"
Set Dest = Workbooks("Voucher Report 26MAR V1.0.xlsm").Worksheets.add _
           after:=Workbooks("Voucher Report 26MAR V1.0.xlsm").Worksheets.Count _
           Name:="My New Sheet"
DestRow = 10
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = "c:\Vouchers\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.csv??")

Do While fileName <> ""
  'assign the opened workbook to a var for easier use
  set source = Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
  For Each sheet In source.Worksheets
    'copy the UsedRange cells from the sheet
    '.copy is kind of weird, but this works
    sheet.cells(1,1).resize(sheet.usedrange.rows.count, sheet.usedrange.columns.count).copy
    'paste doesn't apply to a range, but to a worksheet object
    '   the destination param tells it where to go
    dest.paste destination:=range(cells(destrow,"A")
    'increment the current row pointer but the number of rows used
    destrow = destrow + sheet.usedrange.rows.count
  Next sheet
  Workbooks(fileName).Close
  fileName = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

All code untested, so you may have some minor tweaks. I'd suggest commenting out the `ScreenUpdating` lines until you have it all working correctly.

Note: I found the references for `.copy` here in the [MS Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760%28v=office.14%29.aspx), and for `.paste` here in the [MS Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821951%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: I couldn't get the Dest working so i changed it to:     Set Dest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
           Dest.Name = "My New Sheet" which does add a newsheet but now im having problems with the copy part error 1004

Comment: It seems `.copy` and `.paste` are a little different in the way they work. Check the updated code